# Is server side session storage not enabled in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

In [Rails security code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) it is stated that sessions are stored by default as cookies in client side, however it doesn't state how to switch to server side storage. It just says:

> Rails provides several storage mechanisms for the session hashes. The
> most important is ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore

I have made some search and according to this [blog](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activerecord-sessionstore-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013):

> As of Rails 4, the Active Record session store has be removed from the core framework and is now deprecated.

And it says there is a Gem for server side storage, but it says there is no guaranteed support for versions of Rails 4.1 and higher.

So is there no core support for server side session storage in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is support for server-side session storage - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

The relevant bits:

> The session is only available in the controller and the view and can use one of a number of different storage mechanisms:
>
> ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore - Stores everything on the client.
> ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore - Stores the data in the Rails cache.
> ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore - Stores the data in a database using > Active Record. (require activerecord-session_store gem).
> ActionDispatch::Session::MemCacheStore - Stores the data in a memcached cluster (this is a legacy implementation; consider using CacheStore instead).

and...

> If you need a different session storage mechanism, you can change it in the config/initializers/session_store.rb file

If you search around you'll also find other server-side session storage options which are not part of the Rails core, using things such as Redis.